# Feynman diagram using TikZ-Feynman package

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman

I tried to use TikZ-Feynman package to plot Feynman diagram as shown in [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Feynman_diagrams#Loading_the_Package).

I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
    i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
        a -- [photon] b,
        f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
    };

\end{document}
```

it should give me

[image]

but I got:

[image]

what is the problem?

Comment: You should have a warning like this in your .log file: "LuaTeX is required if you wish to have vertices automatically placed."

Answer (score 6):

This probably happens because of the TeX engine: if I compile your code with LuaLaTeX I get the expected output, but if I compile it with pdfLaTeX I get the same problematic output as you. As stated in the package's [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman), the automatic calculation of the vertices' positions is done with a Lua script, so it requires LuaTeX.

If you don't want to use LuaTeX, another solution would be to place vertices manually, as explained in section 2.4.3 of the documentation.

Comment: Indeed the problem is because of the TeX engine. I solved it by setting 
``` % !TeX TS-program = lualatex```  in the top of the Tex file